# Please assist me I can't seem to fix this error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I'm trying to plot my machine learning model graphs but I keep getting an error saying

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)
```

How can I fix this??

My code is as follows:

```
val_accuracy = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs = range(len(accuracy))
plt.figure(figsize=(18,12))
plt.plot(epochs, accuracy, 'bo', label='Training accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs, val_accuracy, 'r', label='Validation accuracy')
plt.title('Training & Validation accuracy')
plt.legend()

plt.figure(figsize=(18,12))
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'bo', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training & Validation loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: pretty hard to diagnose without access to your `history.history` data. But, you can start to debug the problem by printing out the length of each array you are trying to plot - it seems for at least one of them, there is only one datapoint. i.e., `print(len(epochs), len(accuracy), len(val_accuracy), len(val_loss))`.

Comment: Which line raised the error?